# Some misunderstand about casting in generic function

Tags: c, casting, pointer-arithmetic

I have some misunderstanding of the tutorial from my class. There is function called `print_Arr()`, it's generic function that gets pointer to arrays of double or integers and prints it.

Here is the code:

```
int  main() {
    int  a[] = { 2,7,6,4,1 };
    double b[] = { 12.5,2.7,3.0,5.5,5.9,1.0 };

    print_Arr(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(int), print_int);
    print_Arr(b, sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]), sizeof(double), print_double);
}

void print_Arr(void* a, int size, int m, void (*print_func)(void* )) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= size-1; i++)
    {
        print_func((char*)a + m*i);
    }
}

void print_int(int* p) {

    printf("%d\n", *p);
}

void print_double(double* num) {

    printf("%f\n", *num);
}
```

Why do I have to make cast `a` to `(char*)` in this row:

```
print_func((char*)a + m*i);
```

I sent to `print_Arr()` generic function two type of arrays integers or doubles, 
thus it is logically to cast `a` to `int *` or to `double*`.

But why is it casted to `char*`? What do I miss?

Comment: How would you decide inside `print_Arr` whether to cast to `int` or `double`? You can't really do that

Comment: The code in the question is not really right either - rather, full of misunderstandings. `print_int` and `print_double` are not compatible with `print_func`; `i` and `m` should perhaps be of type `size_t` - especially with the prototype not declared beforehand!

Answer (score 4):

First, a word on ***why*** the cast is needed:

Pointer arithmetic makes use of the **size of the type being pointed to**. `void` is a forever incomplete type, that cannot be completed, so pointer arithmetic is not possible on a pointer to `void` type.

To add, for the additive operators, quoting from `C11`, chapter §6.5.6, constraints:

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one operand shall be a
>   **pointer to a complete object type** and the other shall have integer type.

and, from chapter §6.2.5,

> The `void` type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete object type that
>   cannot be completed.

---

That said, why the cast is to `char*` :

Pointer arithmetic makes use of the type being pointed to. Quoting the spec once again

> [...] if the expression `P` points to
>   the `i`-th element of an array object, the expressions `(P)+N` (equivalently, `N+(P))` and
>   `(P)-N` (where `N` has the value `n`) point to, respectively, the `i+n`-th and `i−n`-th elements of
>   the array object, provided they exist.

Here, look at your construct:

```
      ((char*)a + m*i);
```

where `m` is the size of the actual object type pointed to by the actual argument. So, if you cast the pointer to the actual type, the calculation would be wrong. To present a comparison, say:

- `sizeof (char)` is 1, mandated by standard.
- `sizeof (int)` == 4 , say in your platform.

So, for an array `int arr[ ] = {1, 2, 3, 4}`, the expressions

- `(char*)a + (sizeof(int)*1)`
  and
- `(int*) a + 1`

are equivalent.

Finally, touching the topic of converting another type of pointer to `char*` and accessing it:

> [...] When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
>   the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the
>   result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object. [....]

Answer (score 3):

You need the `char *` cast because you do pointer arithmetic on the pointer, to get a  byte offset from the beginning, but you can't do that on a `void *`.

Comment: it is too short .and dont have code .please change ur  bad habits .to learn more see " Learn more about formatting"

Answer (score 0):

A void pointer doesn't have a type size, so you can't calculate with it.

Comment: Nitpicking: The `void`-pointer *has* as size, namely `sizeof (void*)`. Still what it points to does not have a size. `sizeof(void)` is not a valid statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
    public:

       int num=0;

       int c;
    int doubleToChar(double a){
       while ((a-1)>=0){
        num++;

       }
       c=a;
       return a*10;

    }/*    int doubleToCharhundred(double a){
       while ((a-1)>=0){
        num++;

       }

       return a*100-c;

    }*/
    double a=12.12345;
    char *tenDivide ;
    char *intPart;
    //u can add hundred or thousand by another char;
    tenDivide =doubleToChar(a);
    if(num<128)
      intPart=num; 
    else{
      while(num-1){
           //same  doubleToChar
       }
    }
```